# Remove elements on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering, if it is possible to delete `<li>` `<img>` and `<a href>` (all three at a time) when clicking on a delete icon beside them?

If so, what event should I be using? I know that I should be using click event, but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Why is it off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery .remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is what you're looking for. If you want to implement a delete button as part of a `<li>` element, you could do it like this:

HTML

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="http://google.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></a> <a class="delete" href="#" onclick="delete()">X</a></li> 
        <li>test</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

In jQuery, `$(this)` will return the current element (in this case, the delete "button" that was clicked), and `.parent()` will go up one level in the DOM tree. So, `$(this).parent().remove()` will remove the `<li>` that the delete link is contained.

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cqmwb6fg/)

Comment: Yes, but I have a delete icon beside it. When I click on the del icon, it should delete the whole section (<li> , <img> , <a href> and itself)

Comment: It is working but however it is appearing again when I am refreshing the page! That is why I was asking for PERMANENT delete?

Comment: That isn't possible unless you are loading this data from a server, and implement an API call to handle a delete action or something along those lines. We need more details of your situation, then.